# Executing Linux commands from webpage

Tags: javascript, php, html, linux, web-development-server

I have set up a very basic website on apache2 server (running on Ubuntu 18.04). The website has just one page. I used some JavaScript to add dynamic content to it, and the website contains HTML form, which sends data to MySql server -- I connected to the database with PHP.

Based on user input, I need to execute a certain Linux terminal command (say: `ls -l`). For example, if user inputs first and last names and clicks on Submit button, the `ls -l` command will automatically execute without user doing anything in terminal. Is this possible?
This is the HTML form I have:

```
<form method="post">
    <label>Fisrt Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" required></label>
    <label>Last Name: <input type="text" name="lastname" required></label>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Edited:
Ok so I have this PHP code right now in addition to code that connects to MySql database:

```
<?php
    $output = shell_exec('sudo addgroup test2');
    echo "<pre>$output</pre>;

    $result = exec('echo $?');
    echo "$result";
?>
```

However, it does not add this group and `echo $?` returns 0. However, when I substitute `shell_exec('sudo addgroup test2');` with `shell_exec('ls -l');` -- it works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: so, `ls -l` will be run on the server - so you'd need to show how you intend to do that in server side code

Comment: So I do not really know yet how to do that in server side code. I need some guidance

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Comment: Thanks. So this code will be run on the server the website is hosted, correct?

Comment: which code? you haven't shown any code

Comment: Please check the Edited part

Comment: *"Based on user input, I need to execute a certain Linux terminal command ..."* - Good luck with that...

Comment: Actually not based on user input. Jast when the user clicks on Submit button.

Answer (score 0):

This need to be handled by the backend server code running behind Apache. You may pass the commands as a query string or as POST json from UI and write a server-side script (in php) to catch the parameters and execute the function as `shell-exec` http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php .

Comment: Please check the Edited part

Comment: Try this snippet.
`<?php
    $output = shell_exec('touch /tmp/created_from_php');
    echo("<pre>$output</pre>");
?>`

To verify check `/tmp/created_from_php` path after executing.

Comment: A reason for `sudo addgroup test2` is the user php is running may not have `sudo/root` priveledge. Like if you are running php with `www-data` user then it may not have `sudo` access.

Comment: Replace above shell_exec function with simple sudo commands like `sudo touch /etc/created_from_php` and if it does not work then it is the php user privilege issue.

Comment: I have tried `shell_exec('touch /tmp/created_from_php');` but it did not work out for me. And you are right, it looks like I am running php with `www-data` user. When I do `exec('whoami');` -- it returns `www-data`

Comment: What if its a command that takes lot of time for eg  a huge bash script to start a machine or something like that, or what if its a command that gives continuous output like top, how do companies like digitalocean gives a loding... and run the script and get its output.